# Guess that number game

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a python project "Guess that number" where the computer chooses some random number from the given range and the user has to guess that number within 5 tries. If the user successfully guesses the number, he would be redirected to the next level. Else, the game is over.
When The user cannot guess that number the should be over but in my case, it is again asking for the same level and there is no output of game over. Here's my code:

```
from random import randint
level = 1
points = [100,75,50,25,10]
points_scored = 0
play = True
while play:
    while level != 0:
        end_value = level * 10
        secret_number = randint(1,end_value)
        for counter in range(0,5):
            #gets the guessing number as user input
            guess_number = int(input("Guess the secret number between 1 and {} ({} attempts left):".format(end_value,5-counter)))
            #check guessing number is correct or higher or lower
            if secret_number == guess_number:
                print("Your Guess is Correct, You Won the level {} with {} points".format(level,points[counter]))
                points_scored += points[counter]
                level = level + 1
                break
            elif guess_number < secret_number:
                print("Your Guess is lower than secret number")
            elif guess_number > secret_number:
                print("Your Guess is higher than secret number")
            else:#else of for statement
                print("Game Over, You Loose the Game, secret number is {} and your total scores are".format(secret_number, points[counter]))
                break
    else:#else of while statement
        print("Congratz, You Won the Game with {} !!!".format(points_scored))
        again=str(input("Do you want to play again, type yes or no "))
        if again == "no":
            play = False
           quit()
```

I am attaching Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: There is no such thing as an else statement for a loop. You need to check if the counter is too high and then end the game

Comment: No such thing as an else statement of a loop?????

Comment: @LiorDahan there is actually an else statement for loops (which OP should be using here)

Comment: @LiorDahan you are wrong. Read the docs about `for`...

Comment: You are probably thinking of... every language besides python

Comment: Even after removing the else statement the program is still not executing "Game over" print statement

Comment: Actually... they are right, there is an [else clause on loops](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)... I'm just baffled.

Comment: There is an indentation error for quit().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have written the code is correct but it is looping again. I made some modifications to your code using while loop.

```
from random import randint
level = 1
points = [100,75,50,25,10]
points_scored = 0
play = True
while play:
    while level != 0:
        end_value = level * 10
        secret_number = randint(1,end_value)
        counter=0
        while counter<5:
            #gets the guessing number as user input
            guess_number = int(input("Guess the secret number between 1 and {} ({} attempts left):".format(end_value,5-counter)))
            #check guessing number is correct or higher or lower
            if secret_number == guess_number:
                print("Your Guess is Correct, You Won the level {} with {} points".format(level,points[counter]))
                points_scored += points[counter]
                level = level + 1
                break
            elif guess_number < secret_number:
                print("Your Guess is lower than secret number")
            elif guess_number > secret_number:
                print("Your Guess is higher than secret number")
            counter=counter+1
            if(counter>4):
                print("Game Over, You Loose the Game, secret number is {} and your total scores are{}".format(secret_number, points[counter-1]))
                break
        break

    print("Congratz, You Won the Game with {} !!!".format(points_scored))
    again=str(input("Do you want to play again, type yes or no "))
    if again == "no":
        play = False
        quit()
    else:
        level=1
```

Here, game over will be printed when the number of guesses are exceeded.

Comment: I don't understand why this is the accepted answer, it doesn't work as expected. The `break` in the last line in the `while level != 0:` loop is executed regardless of the user having won or lost, making them go to the `Do you want to play again...` chunk and resetting the level every time.

Answer (score 2):

The logic is almost completely right but there is a big problem in your code. Think of the conditions you have set in the most inner loop:

```
if secret_number == guess_number:
    ...
elif guess_number < secret_number:
    ...
elif guess_number > secret_number:
    ...
else:
    # How can a number be not equal, not bigger, and not smaller than another number???
```

I think some refactoring could be made to make the code even cleaner and perform correctly:

```
from random import randint
level = 1
points = [100, 75, 50, 25, 10]
points_scored = 0
# No need to use the play variable, the program exits in the end with "quit" if the user doesn't want to keep playing
# You don't seem to set the level as 0 anywhere so why not just keep playing until the user loses.
while True:
    end_value = level * 10
    secret_number = randint(1, end_value)
    # The first parameter in range is already 0, no need to explicitly set it
    for counter in range(5):
        # gets the guessing number as user input
        guess_number = int(input("Guess the secret number between 1 and {} ({} attempts left):".format(end_value, 5 - counter )))
        # check guessing number is correct or higher or lower
        if secret_number == guess_number:
            print("Your Guess is Correct, You Won the level {} with {} points".format(level, points[counter]))
            points_scored += points[counter]
            # level += 1 is the same as level = level + 1
            level += 1
            break
        elif guess_number < secret_number:
            print("Your Guess is lower than secret number")
        # This next one could be "else:" because, as stated before,
        # if guess_number is not equal nor smaller than secret_number,
        # it can only be bigger, but it makes no difference.
        elif guess_number > secret_number:
            print("Your Guess is higher than secret number")
    else:
        print("Game Over, You Loose the Game, secret number is {}. You got {} points.".format(secret_number, points_scored))
        # No need to cast the input as str, it's already a string.
        again = input("Do you want to play again, type yes or no ")
        if again == "no":
            quit()
        else:
            level = 1
```

Comment: Thank *you* for making me aware of that you can use `else` in loops

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are coming back to the same level is because your else statement is not executing. One way to correct this would be to remove the else statement and bring it out of the counter loop. Also add a flag to keep the losing status of the player.
Change:

```
elif guess_number > secret_number:
    print("Your Guess is higher than secret number")
else:#else of for statement
    print("Game Over, You Loose the Game, secret number is {} and your total scores are".format(secret_number, points[counter]))
    break
```

to:

```
    elif guess_number > secret_number:
            print("Your Guess is higher than secret number")
if level_lost:
    print("Game Over, You Loose the Game, secret number is {} and your total scores are".format(secret_number, points[counter]))
    level = 0
    break
```

Set the losing status to false if the player correctly guesses the number.

```
while level != 0:
    level_lost = True
    end_value = level * 10
    secret_number = randint(1,end_value)
    for counter in range(0,5):
        #gets the guessing number as user input
        guess_number = int(input("Guess the secret number between 1 and {} ({} attempts left):".format(end_value,5-counter)))
        #check guessing number is correct or higher or lower
        if secret_number == guess_number:
            print("Your Guess is Correct, You Won the level {} with {} points".format(level,points[counter]))
            points_scored += points[counter]
            level = level + 1
            level_lost = False
```

Then finally to restart the game again change

```
if again == "no":
    play = False
```

to:

```
if again == "no":
    play = False
    quit()
else:
    level=1
```